# Signing a XML document in a specific place with Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, cosign-api

I'm signing a XML documento using the **DSA REST Web Services** with the endpoint https://prime-dsa-devctr.docusign.net:8081/sapiws/v1/digital_signature . I've looked over and over at the documentation but I didn't find how to sign in a specific place of the XML file. When I sign it, the signature tag goes to the end of the XML file, but I need to place it in a specific place.

Answer (score 0):

DSA (DocuSign Appliance) is used for digital signature. Unlike our electronic signature product, you sign a file and there are no ways to place the sign in a specific location, because it's for the entire file. If you are looking for a visual way to sign a file, you should first use eSignature. You can do that with our eSignature REST API. Then you can still digitally sign the file if you want to.